# How to resize the QWebEnginePage inside the window in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Can someone please tell me how to resize this QWebEnginePage. When i run this file, it open a window with full browser like site opened, but i want to resize it to add a button and other elements in the window.

**Here is my code:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets, QtWebChannel, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QSizeGrip, QGridLayout
from jinja2 import Template
#import D_scraper

class Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        # self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        # for making the window draggable
        self.oPos = self.pos()
        self.setFixedSize(1000, 650)

        testlw = QVBoxLayout()


        testlo = QGridLayout()
        testlo.addLayout(testlw, 0, 1)

        self.setLayout(testlo)
        self.setWindowTitle('test')
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(255,255,0);')
        self.setStyleSheet('border-radius: 30px')

class Element(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        super(Element, self).__init__(parent)
        self._name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def script(self):
        return ""

class WebEnginePage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WebEnginePage, self).__init__(parent)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.onLoadFinished)
        self._objects = []
        self._scripts = []


    def add_object(self, obj):
        self._objects.append(obj)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def onLoadFinished(self, ok):
        print("Finished loading: ", ok)
        if ok:
            self.load_qwebchannel()
            self.add_objects()

    def load_qwebchannel(self):
        file = QtCore.QFile(":/qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js")
        if file.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly):
            content = file.readAll()
            file.close()
            self.runJavaScript(content.data().decode())
        if self.webChannel() is None:
            channel = QtWebChannel.QWebChannel(self)
            self.setWebChannel(channel)

    def add_objects(self):
        if self.webChannel() is not None:
            objects = {obj.name: obj for obj in self._objects}
            self.webChannel().registerObjects(objects)
            _script = """
            {% for obj in objects %}
            var {{obj}};
            {% endfor %}
            new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
            {% for obj in objects %}
                {{obj}} = channel.objects.{{obj}};
            {% endfor %}
            }); 
            """
            self.runJavaScript(Template(_script).render(objects=objects.keys()))
            for obj in self._objects:
                if isinstance(obj, Element):
                    self.runJavaScript(obj.script())


class Helper(Element):
    classClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def script(self):
        js = """
        document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
            e.preventDefault()
            {{name}}.objectClicked(target.className);
        }, false);"""
        return Template(js).render(name=self.name)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def objectClicked(self, className):
        if className:
            self.classClicked.emit(className)

def on_clicked(name):
    on_clicked.xcv = name
    print(on_clicked.xcv)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Form()
    classname_helper = Helper("classname_helper")
    classname_helper.classClicked.connect(on_clicked)
    view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    page = WebEnginePage()
    page.add_object(classname_helper)
    view.setPage(page)
    view.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=mobiles&as=on&as-show=on&otracker=AS_Query_TrendingAutoSuggest_1_0_na_na_na&otracker1=AS_Query_TrendingAutoSuggest_1_0_na_na_na&as-pos=1&as-type=TRENDING&suggestionId=mobiles&requestId=4720716a-cf2f-4822-9036-c66b9542d2d6"))
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am new to QT Framework so got this problem. Can you please add a button along with the resized browser inside the window for an example, so that i could understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a "container" widget, and embed the view in that.

You were half-way from there, as you already created a widget, you only have to correctly set the layout to that widget, and add children widgets to it.

```
class Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('test')
        self.setMinimumSize(320, 240)
        self.resize(640, 480)

        testlo = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(testlo)

        self.testButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('test button')
        testlo.addWidget(self.testButton)

        self.testLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('test label')
        # add a label in the first row of the grid, second column
        testlo.addWidget(self.testLabel, 0, 1)

        self.view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        # add the view to the second row, but let it occupy two columns
        testlo.addWidget(self.view, 1, 0, 1, 2)

        classname_helper = Helper("classname_helper")
        classname_helper.classClicked.connect(on_clicked)
        self.page = WebEnginePage()
        self.page.add_object(classname_helper)
        self.view.setPage(self.page)
        self.view.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=mobiles&as=on&as-show=on&otracker=AS_Query_TrendingAutoSuggest_1_0_na_na_na&otracker1=AS_Query_TrendingAutoSuggest_1_0_na_na_na&as-pos=1&as-type=TRENDING&suggestionId=mobiles&requestId=4720716a-cf2f-4822-9036-c66b9542d2d6"))

        # if you call setStyleSheet() multiple times, it always overwrites the
        # previously set stylesheet, just use it once with the full contents
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            background-color: rgb(255,255,0);
            border-radius: 30px;
        ''')

# ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Form()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Yeah well now it does showing me 2 windows instead. I Want the same window to open and resize the window in it. The ```class Form()``` code in the first was removed because i mistakenly added it. Can you make changes in the WebEnginePage named class itself?

Comment: Please carefully follow my example, especially the last lines.